# How take the date object from selectedDates in onChange and extract the month and day

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, flatpickr

How take the date object from selectedDates in onChange and extract the month and day from it and put them where i need them ( in a another, separate div, with my styling)

```
<div>
  <p>CHECK IN</p>
  <input id="" class="datepicker-from" placeholder=" ">
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker-from').flatpickr({
    plugins: [new rangePlugin({
      input: '.datepicker-to'
    })],
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "M j",
    dateFormat: "m-d",
    position: "below",
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: "today",
    maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(210) // 14 days from now
  });
});
```

Comment: There is a [onChange](https://flatpickr.js.org/events/#onchange) callback function in the initialization options that you can use to add your logic.

Comment: thanks @Shidersz but the onChange only works when i click de input, and I want to change its styles at the beginning